# Acumatica doesn't see third party files I need to include in the customization package

Tags: acumatica, smartsheet-api

I have a customization that uses the Smartsheet API, but when publishing to another site, it gets dependency errors for the third party files.

I'm trying to include ALL the files added by the NuGet manager, but Acumatica doesn't see them all, so I can't include them in the 'Files' section of my customization package.

Does anyone know how to include files in the 'bin' folder that Acumatica can't seem to see or find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acumatica support provided the following answer:

> "You can remove the file from the exclusion list 'files.list' located
> at the root folder of IIS virtual directory for the website.   It's
> not a good idea if you are going to replace libraries used by
> Acumatica like .NET Framework because you can replace it with
> incompatible versions."

The solution is to find/add the version of the third party API (in this case the Smartsheet SDK) which has dependencies on the files (in this case the RestSharp and NewtonSoft dlls) that are already provided / included by Acumatica.